# Как сменить настройки my.ini/my.cnf динамически?

Tags: sql, mysql

Привет.
Посмотреть установленные настройки сервера можно командой

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'name_variable'
```

Какой командой можно сменить значение установленных переменных в файле `my.ini`?
Какой уровень привилегий позволяет это сделать?
Когда настройка вступить в силу(после перезапуска сервера или нет)?

Как создать свою глобальную переменную?

```
 SET uoi=90;
```

**ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'uoi'**

Answer (score 3):

Сменить значение серверной переменной можно при помощи оператора `SET`, который вы привели в вопросе. Существует несколько вариантов его использования:

```
SET GLOBAL init_connect='SET autocommit=0';
```

или

```
SET @@init_connect='SET autocommit=0';
```

или

```
SET init_connect='SET autocommit=0';
```

Не все пользователи могут изменять серверные переменные, нужно обладать привилегией `SUPER`, чтобы сервер позволил это сделать. Не все переменные можно изменять на лету при помощи `SET`. Уточнять список изменяемых переменных можно [в документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html). Если переменная обозначена как Dynamic - она может быть изменена при помощи SET, если в поле Dynamic стоит No - изменять ее можно либо на уровне конфигурационного файла, либо вообще нельзя (в последнем случае потребуется перезапуск сервера, или обновление данных конфигурационного файла).

Создать собственную серверную переменную не получится - эти переменные отражение состояния сервера - придется программировать и пересобирать MySQL, чтобы ввести собственную серверную переменную. Однако, можно создать пользовательскую сессионную переменную. Такие переменные, в отличие от системных начинаются не с двух `@@`, а с одной. Для этого нужно либо воспользоваться оператором `SET`

```
SET @uoi = 90;
SELECT @uoi;
+------+
| @uoi |
+------+
|   90 |
+------+
```

Либо задать ее в составе другого запроса, например, `SELECT`

```
SELECT @oui := 100;
```

Обратите внимание, что без оператора `SET` для присвоения значения переменной используется оператор `:=`, а не `=`.